# WebGL Javascript not working :(

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to draw a cylinder, but its not working :(

Can you help?

http://www.nextlevelgeek.com/CylinderWebGL.zip

```
  var gl;
  function initGL(canvas) {
    try {
      gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
      gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
      gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
    } catch(e) {
    }
    if (!gl) {
      alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
    }
  }


  function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!shaderScript) {
      return null;
    }

    var str = "";
    var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
    while (k) {
      if (k.nodeType == 3) {
        str += k.textContent;
      }
      k = k.nextSibling;
    }

    var shader;
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
      return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
      return null;
    }

    return shader;
  }


  var shaderProgram;
  function initShaders() {
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
      alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

    shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);

    shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
  }


  var mvMatrix;
  var mvMatrixStack = [];

  function mvPushMatrix(m) {
    if (m) {
      mvMatrixStack.push(m.dup());
      mvMatrix = m.dup();
    } else {
      mvMatrixStack.push(mvMatrix.dup());
    }
  }

  function mvPopMatrix() {
    if (mvMatrixStack.length == 0) {
      throw "Invalid popMatrix!";
    }
    mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
    return mvMatrix;
  }

  function loadIdentity() {
    mvMatrix = Matrix.I(4);
  }


  function multMatrix(m) {
    mvMatrix = mvMatrix.x(m);
  }

  function mvTranslate(v) {
    var m = Matrix.Translation($V([v[0], v[1], v[2]])).ensure4x4();
    multMatrix(m);
  }

  function mvRotate(ang, v) {
    var arad = ang * Math.PI / 180.0;
    var m = Matrix.Rotation(arad, $V([v[0], v[1], v[2]])).ensure4x4();
    multMatrix(m);
  }

  var pMatrix;
  function perspective(fovy, aspect, znear, zfar) {
    pMatrix = makePerspective(fovy, aspect, znear, zfar);
  }


  function setMatrixUniforms() {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, new Float32Array(pMatrix.flatten()));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, new Float32Array(mvMatrix.flatten()));
  }


  var triangleVertexPositionBuffer;
  var triangleVertexColorBuffer;
  var multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer;
  var multiTriangleVertexColorBuffer;
  var squareVertexPositionBuffer;
  var squareVertexColorBuffer;
  function initBuffers() {
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
    var vertices = [
         0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  0.0
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 3;

    triangleVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexColorBuffer);
    var colors = [
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    triangleVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
    triangleVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 3;

    multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer);

    var segments = 10; // Higher numbers improve quality 
    var radius = 3;    // The radius (width) of the cylinder
    var height = 10;   // The height of the cylind
    var PI = 3.14159265;

    var vertices = new Array(segments*3*2);
    var v = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < segments; x++)  
        {
            var theta = (x / (segments - 1)) * 2 * PI;
            vertices[v]= radius * Math.cos(theta); //x
            v++;
            vertices[v]= height * y; //y
            v++;
            vertices[v]= radius * Math.sin(theta); //z
            v++;
        }
    }

    var indices = new Array(segments*6);
    var v = 0;
    for (var  x = 0; x < segments - 1; x++)
    {
        indices[v]=x;
        v++;
        indices[v]=x + segments;
        v++;
        indices[v]=x + segments + 1;
        v++;

        indices[v]=x + segments + 1;
        v++;
        indices[v]=x+ 1;
        v++;
        indices[v]=x;
        v++;
    }

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = segments;

    multiTriangleVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, multiTriangleVertexColorBuffer);
    var colors = [
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    multiTriangleVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
    multiTriangleVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 3;
    alert(dump(indices,colors));

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    squareVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
    vertices = [
         1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  0.0
    ];

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 4;

    squareVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexColorBuffer);
    colors = []
    for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) {
      colors = colors.concat([0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0]);
    }
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    squareVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
    squareVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 4;
  }

function dump(arr,level) {
    var dumped_text = "";
    if(!level) level = 0;

    //The padding given at the beginning of the line.
    var level_padding = "";
    for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

    if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects 
        for(var item in arr) {
            var value = arr[item];

            if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
                dumped_text += dump(value,level+1);
            } else {
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
            }
        }
    } else { //Stings/Chars/Numbers etc.
        dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
    }
    return dumped_text;
}

  var rTri = 0;
  var rSquare = 0;
  function drawScene() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0);
    loadIdentity();

    mvTranslate([-1.5, 0.0, -7.0])
/* 
    mvPushMatrix();
    mvRotate(rTri, [0, 1, 0]);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexColorBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, triangleVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);

    mvPopMatrix();


    mvTranslate([3.0, 0.0, 0.0])

    mvPushMatrix();
    mvRotate(rSquare, [1, 0, 0]);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexColorBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, squareVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);

    mvPopMatrix(); */

    mvTranslate([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

    mvPushMatrix();
    mvRotate(rTri, [0, 1, 0]);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

   // gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, multiTriangleVertexColorBuffer);
   // gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, multiTriangleVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);

    mvPopMatrix();  
  }


  var lastTime = 0;
  function animate() {
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    if (lastTime != 0) {
      var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;

      rTri += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
      rSquare += (75 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
    }
    lastTime = timeNow;
  }


  function tick() {
    drawScene();
    animate();
  }


  function webGLStart() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson03-canvas");
    initGL(canvas);
    initShaders()
    initBuffers();

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    gl.clearDepth(1.0);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

    setInterval(tick, 15);
  }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I had to start with upgrading my driver so it would have opengl support.

Comment: upgrade your drivers? im using mozzila and chrome nightly builds, im having problems getting firebug etc. to work with them though

Comment: also the error .. its non existant .. its a blank screen .. webgl is different. ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a start.  You're not supplying the cylinder colors.  Instead of

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, multiTriangleVertexColorBuffer);
var colors = [
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
];
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

you need something like this to match the number of cylinder vertices:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, multiTriangleVertexColorBuffer);
colors = []
for (var i=0; i < segments*3*2; i++) {
  colors = colors.concat([1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]);
}
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Then you need to uncomment the lines

```
   // gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, multiTriangleVertexColorBuffer);
   // gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, multiTriangleVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Once you've done this you'll see an object rotating in the scene.  It's not a cylinder, but you can probably debug the shape now that you can see it.

For starters, I think instead of

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = segments;
```

you need

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
multiTriangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = segments*2;
```

And then rather than draw this as `gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP`, look ahead to [Lesson 4](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=370) to see how to use `gl.TRIANGLES`. (This is where you can use your indices array)

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked.

Changed from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js" />
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js" ></script>
```